# Как выводить данные из консоли в отдельном окне в программе c++

Tags: c++, windows, bat, виджет

У меня есть bat файл, который выполняет установку некоторых файлов и эта установка может занять некоторое время и также может привести к ошибке. Я бы хотел сделать в своей (на QTWidgets) программе отдельное окошко вроде такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в которое будет выводиться вся информация из консоли.
И если такое сделать невозможно, подскажите, как мне ловить ошибка из той же консоли и выводить их в программу (например, textlabel)

Comment: Что значит *ошибки*? Если вы используете bat, то единственное вам оставаться парсить stderr из дочернего процесса.

Comment: А можно весь лог консоли выводить в отдельное (не всплывающее) окно, как на картинке?

Comment: Просто перенаправить stdout в элемент.

Comment: Например можно создать элемент graphicsView и выводить туда с помощью: freopen("имя bat файла", "r+", stdout);? Просто я ещё плохо разбираюсь в этом

Comment: Я в Qt сам не разбираюсь сильно (Только из моего прошлого опыта). Я думаю, что достаточно использовать сигналы readyRead и соединить их с слотами любого нужного виджета (Например, TextArea), который поддерживает текстовый вывод. И если уж используете Qt, то используете только его библиотеки. Не стоит смешивать сишные и stl с Qt, так как Qt предоставляет почти 100% нужного функционала и даже больше.

Comment: Вам надо запускать свой bat помощью класса `QProcess` там есть возможность получать раздельно stdin и stderr, строка для формирования команды `QString("cmd /C \"%1\"").arg(cmd)`